# Connecting to a remote docker machine using publickey authentication from Windows

Tags: docker, ssh, docker-machine

I'm attempting to connect to a remote docker host (Ubuntu 16.04) from windows server 2008, all of this lives on AWS EC2. There is a requirement to run docker within a single EC2 instance, so I'm using a generic driver.

I'm using a public key file (.pem) which works for ssh (from putty with extracting ppk and as is when sshing from linux environment) and I'm getting :

```
 Error checking TLS connection: Error checking and/or regenerating the certs: 
 There was an error validating certificates for host "xx.xx.xx.xx:2376": dial tcp xx.xx.xx.xx:2376: connectex: 
 No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

Is this possible? Should I convert the pem file to another format? I've tried converting the certificate to a number of formats and that didn't work.

Comment: It's not a problem with your key file. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ssh/2926/debugging-ssh-problems/18370/connection-refused#t=201705081728036080833

Comment: What command do you run? This error has nothing in common with SSH.

Comment: @Jakuje I'm trying to connect to a remote docker host via docker-machine

Comment: @Kenster this is interesting, since I know for sure that the ssh is running on port 22 and this key works for standard ssh connection. Docker-machine config is listing two ports, 22 for ssh port, and 2376 for engine port, and in this case it's refusing to connect on 2376 port in particular.

Comment: I'm probably better of asking on docker github page